# javascript pass parameter as object or something like that

Tags: javascript

I want to create a class like "`MessageBox`". On calling the `Show()` function I will pass the required parameters. Like:

```
MessageBox.Show(
{
  str : "Are you sure?",
  onYes : function(){
   //do something
  },
  onNo: function(){
   // Do another stuff
  }
});
```

What I tried:

```
var MessageBox = {
  Show : function(){ // I stuck here
   }
}
```

Let's suppose within the show the JavaScript `confirm()` function is being called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be something like this :

```
var MessageBox = {
  Show : function(opts){ // I stuck here
      var result = confirm(opts.str);
      if (result) {
        opts.onYes();
      } else {
        opts.onNo();
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just pass an object as parameter:

```
Show: function(obj) {
  var str = obj.str;
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you could just pass it, like

```
var MessageBox = {
  Show : function(params){ // I stuck here
    console.log(params.str); //would give you "Are you sure?"
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
var MessageBox = function() {
    var str = 'put your private variables here';
};

MessageBox.prototype.Show = function(arg) {
    console.log(arg);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this sort of thing like below (including a bit of checking so that the onYes and onNo functions are optional:

```
var MessageBox = {
    Show: function(args) {
        var answer = confirm(args.str);
        if ((answer) && (typeof args.onYes === "function")) {
            args.onYes();
        }
        else if (typeof args.onNo === "function") {
            args.onNo();
        }
    }
 };
```

Then you can use it like you wanted:

```
MessageBox.Show({
   str: "Are you sure?",
   onYes: function(){
    //do something
   },
   onNo: function(){
      // Do another stuff
   }
});
```